# How do I fix the error rm: can't remove '/workspace/source': Resource busy?

Tags: python, openshift

I am currently working on a project for one of my courses and right now as part of one of the tasks they're having us set up a pipeline on OpenShift and add tasks. The first task I am trying to add is the cleanup task which was already created in the terminal. When I tried to add the task to the newly created pipeline I get an rm: can't remove '/workspace/source': Resource busy error. What does that mean and how do I fix this error? This is what my code for the cleanup task looks in the file;

```html
---
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: Task
metadata:
  name: cleanup
spec:
  description: This task will clean up a workspace by deleting all the files
  workspaces:
    - name: source
  steps:
    - name: remove
      image: alpine:3
      env:
        - name: WORKSPACE_SOURCE_PATH
          value: $(workspaces.source.path)
      workingDir: $(workspaces.source.path)
      securityContext:
        runAsNonRoot: false
        runAsUser: 0
      script: |
        set -eu
        echo "Removing all files from ${WORKSPACE_SOURCE_PATH} ..."
   
        if [ -d "${WORKSPACE_SOURCE_PATH}" ] ; then
          rm -rf "${WORKSPACE_SOURCE_PATH:?}"
        fi
---
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: Task
metadata:
  name: nose
spec:
  workspaces:
    - name: source
  params:
    - name: args
      description: Arguments to pass to nose
      type: string
      default: "-v"
  steps:
    - name: nosetests
      image: python:3.9-slim
      workingDir: $(workspaces.source.path)
      script: |
        set -e
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel
        pip install -r requirements.txt
        nosetests $(params.args)
```

```
---
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: Task
metadata:
  name: cleanup
spec:
  description: This task will clean up a workspace by deleting all the files
  workspaces:
    - name: source
  steps:
    - name: remove
      image: alpine:3
      env:
        - name: WORKSPACE_SOURCE_PATH
          value: $(workspaces.source.path)
      workingDir: $(workspaces.source.path)
      securityContext:
        runAsNonRoot: false
        runAsUser: 0
      script: |
        set -eu
        echo "Removing all files from ${WORKSPACE_SOURCE_PATH} ..."
   
        if [ -d "${WORKSPACE_SOURCE_PATH}" ] ; then
          rm -rf "${WORKSPACE_SOURCE_PATH:?}"
        fi
---
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: Task
metadata:
  name: nose
spec:
  workspaces:
    - name: source
  params:
    - name: args
      description: Arguments to pass to nose
      type: string
      default: "-v"
  steps:
    - name: nosetests
      image: python:3.9-slim
      workingDir: $(workspaces.source.path)
      script: |
        set -e
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel
        pip install -r requirements.txt
        nosetests $(params.args)
```

I dont know how to resolve this problem so I need someone's help regarding this issue and how to resolve it

Comment: You have used mark-up for JavaScript and tagged the question Python.  This code is neither.  Moreover your mark-up is not correct for presenting code in SO which uses Markdown syntax.

Comment: `rm -rf "${WORKSPACE_SOURCE_PATH:?}"` is an attempt to remove a directory, but the comment suggests an intent to remove the directory content which would be `rm -rf "${WORKSPACE_SOURCE_PATH:?}/*"`

Comment: The message "resource busy" suggests that file or directory is currently open, perhaps in another process, and so cannot be removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
workspaces:
- name: source
steps:
- name: remove
  ...
  env:
    - name: WORKSPACE_SOURCE_PATH
      value: $(workspaces.source.path)
  workingDir: $(workspaces.source.path)
  script: |
  ...
      rm -rf "${WORKSPACE_SOURCE_PATH:?}"
```

`"${WORKSPACE_SOURCE_PATH}"`is the mount point for the workspace and is the "working dir" where the script runs...
you can not delete it (it's busy...), maybe  you want to "empty" the workspace, in this case use

```
rm -rf "${WORKSPACE_SOURCE_PATH}/*"
```